# How to split and iterate over a string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

On a React Page inside `render` I have the code below, which produces the error:

> topic.language.map is not a function

```
{console.log(JSON.stringify(topic.language))}   //this returns "English,French,Other"
{topic.language.map(
    (ln, i) => {
        return (
            <div
                key={i}
                className="language"
            >
                {ln}
            </div>
        );
    }
)}
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I map the different languages? Do I need `.split` instead of `.map`? What would that look like?

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(topic.language)`? No need to json encode.

Comment: @evolutionxbox It's perfectly valid output if the input was *a string…!*

Comment: @evolutionxbox `"English,French,Other"`, including the double quotes, _is_ valid JSON. But it also means, that they do not have an array here, but just a string value with commas in it - which of course explains, why calling `map` on it doesn't work either.

Comment: Output of `console.log(topic.language)` is `English,French,Other`.

Comment: Well then, it's *a string,* not an array.

Comment: And yes, if you want to treat it as an array, `split` it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `language` value is a string, you will need to split the string into an array before calling `map`.

```js
const topic = { language: 'English,French,Other' };

topic.language.split(/,/g).map((ln, i) => {
  console.log(ln);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//assuming your string is like "part1,part2,part3......partn"
//you can just use 
//this will return an array of string spitted by your delimiter 
//here is ',' comma 
//put that is split method and you will be good to go
let stringSplitArray = "part1,part2,part3,part4".split(",")
//now you can do 

stringSplitArray.map(element=>(
  <div>{element}</div>
))
```